# What is the opposite of "emerging markets"?

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a corporate presentation in which I explain how our sales and operations network across the globe enables us to benefit from the opportunities offered by both emerging and "old" markets:

> We have developed our network into a strong global presence, adding
>   further partners in key areas across the globe. Our strategic
>   production and sales footprint grants us a vantage position to tap
>   into the exciting potential of both emerging and ??? markets.

What word should go in place of "???"? Developed markets doesn't sound right, also Consolidated markets means something slightly different.

Any idea on what the "consensus definition" is for this?

Comment: The opposite? Well, a disappearing market, I’d say.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Established` markets is my suggestion

Answer (score 7):

At my place of work (large international company) we refer to "mature markets"

Comment: Yeah, that sounds good too, I'll keep that in mind thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

developed, mature, saturated, advanced or traditional markets.

Answer (score 0):

**Emerged**

is used by some analysts for a market that is no longer emerging, but recently established.

> "**Don't Ignore This Emerged Market**
>   This previously labeled emerging market is now the seventeenth most developed in the world. It has grown its GDP by 7% per year over the past 10 years, and has an unemployment rate of 6.6%."([seekingalpha.com](http://seekingalpha.com/article/1116281-dont-ignore-this-emerged-market))

and

> "Over the past three decades, China’s economy has experienced robust growth as it shifts from a third-world country to a modern consumer economy and influential source of economic power. The view that China can be categorized within “emerging markets” no longer holds true, and a more accurate investment allocation to the Asian nation should be similar to those of other developed countries. **In essence, China is no longer emerging, but rather, has emerged**." ([thinkadvisor.com](http://www.thinkadvisor.com/2012/02/01/china-an-emerged-market))